# how to avoid receiving listener for background activity when dialog is foreground?

Tags: android

I would like to know how to solve a problem I've got. Camera activity is running, and there's a dialog which is generated by a service of other app. When back key pressed, both dialog and main activity receive the key event listener. However, I just want that only the dialog receive the key event listener, not main activity.

Comment: It's not able to add source code to background activity. I can handle only the service and dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onBackPressed() {
   dialog.cancel();
 // Simply Dismiss the dialog to make it close and return to back..

}
```

Set an onClickListener on the back button and do nothing in it. So, the dialog will be closed on pressing the back button but your app would not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can just disable the back press event of Activity by overriding `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing
}
```